# Ionic 2 Popover dismiss

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic2, ionic3

I have a popover, that takes me to another page, where I pop back to the root page (popToRoot), reload the data/dom on an event and then dismiss the popup in the promise when the json data comes back from the server. It all works fine if I have a large timeout on the dismiss.

```
  dismissPopup() {
    if (this.popover) {
      let that = this;
      setTimeout(function () {
        that.popover.dismiss();
      }, 500);
    }
  }
```

If I make the timeout too low, say 100ms, it does not dismiss because the dom is still loading.

However, I don't think having a timeout is probably the best practice. What happens if someone has a slow devise, and the time is not enough?

Can anyone please make any suggestions? Should I detect when the dom has loaded, and then call dismiss? How do I check if the dom had loaded?

Thanks

Comment: This is an old question, but could you please mark any of the answers (if it helped)  as accepted so we can close it? Thanks :)

Answer (score 5):

Instead of using a timeout, you can use [Events](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/util/Events/#events). By doing that, you can *publish* and event when the data comes back from the server (and everything is ready) and *subscribe* to that event to know when you need to dismiss the popup.

```
import { Events } from 'ionic-angular';

constructor(public events: Events) {}

// first page (publish an event when data is ready)
events.publish('loading:finished', data);

// second page (listen for the loading finished event)
events.subscribe('loading:finished', (eventData) => {
  // eventData is an array of parameters, so grab our first and only arg
  console.log('Data:', eventData[0]);
});
```

Answer (score 3):

The popover can also be dismissed from within the popover's view by calling the dismiss() method on the ViewController

```html
  constructor(public navParams:NavParams,public navCtrl:NavController,public viewController:ViewController) {
    console.log('Hello PopOverComponent Component');
  }
  blah()
  {
  //do something
    this.viewController.dismiss();
  }
```